# Open vnc from a list or IP using one sub only

Tags: excel, vba, shell, vnc

I have a list of ip addresses in an excel that connects to other machines remotely using vnc. in column A i have the IP and in column B I have the button that when clicked, it opens the vnc with the IP from the column A. Each of the below sub is assigned to the buttons in Column B-- I manually assigned them from the worksheet.

This is my code:

```
Sub TVM_conn01()
    Shell "C:\Program Files\VNC\tvnviewer.exe " & Cells(1, 1).Value, vbMaximizedFocus
End Sub
Sub TVM_conn02()
    Shell "C:\Program Files\VNC\tvnviewer.exe " & Cells(2, 1).Value, vbMaximizedFocus
End Sub
Sub TVM_conn03()
    Shell "C:\Program Files\VNC\tvnviewer.exe " & Cells(3, 1).Value, vbMaximizedFocus
End Sub
Sub TVM_conn04()
    Shell "C:\Program Files\VNC\tvnviewer.exe " & Cells(4, 1).Value, vbMaximizedFocus
End Sub
Sub TVM_conn05()
    Shell "C:\Program Files\VNC\tvnviewer.exe " & Cells(5, 1).Value, vbMaximizedFocus
End Sub
```

Is there a way I can shorten this? I have 60 machines, I need to create the same for another new 300 machines.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How about a method where you select the cell with the IP address in it, then click a single button. The button would run a `main` method which runs the `shell` command with the value of the active cell.

```
Sub Main
Shell “C:\Programs Files\VNC\tvnviewer.exe” & ActiveCell.Value
End Sub
```

You could even assign the Sub to a keyboard shortcut. Then a button isn’t necessary for the user in the workbook all of the time.